# Fetch result in form of List of java.util.map from hibernate query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2

```
final List <Map<String , Object>>  roleList;
final Map<Integer, String> roleMap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();

roleList = getSession()
    .createQuery("select Id, Name from Emp where dept=:ref")
    .setParameter("ref", "accounts")
    .list();

for (Map<String, Object> map2 : roleList) 
{
    roleMap.put((Integer)(map2.get("Id")), (String)map2.get("Name"));
}

MappingBean.setRoleList(roleMap);
```

The above code is showing class cast exception `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Map`.
Is there any way in Hibernate we can get data in the form of List of Maps? My `roleList` is in the form of map and I want to set the `roleList`.

Comment: What type exactly has your *roleList*?

Comment: take a look at `Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP`

Comment: @EelLee it is of type Map of String and Object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make a select like that:

```
.createQuery("select Id, Name from Emp where dept=:ref")
```

Hibernate returns by default a `List<Object[]>`, because that's the safest way to represent a given subset of fields that by no means are bound to have the same type (hence, the lowest common class is considered `Object`).

You can, however and given the case, transform the result into a map with a simple iteration or through the use of configurations. IMO it *seems* like an excercise in futility because each record will be returned in a `key - Value` fashioned way already (even if it is represented as an array of two objects).

Avoid yourself such overhead by doing this, directly (change the type of `roleList`):

```
for (Object[] role : roleList) 
{
    roleMap.put((Integer)role[0]), (String)role[1]);
}
```

The `Object[]` returned by Hibernate respects the order of the selected fields so, in your case, index `0` corresponds to `Id` and `1` to `Name`.

Comment: final List <Map<String , Object>>  roleList My list is of type Map so y didnt it give me error at first place

Comment: @AnkitDuggal Because you created `roleList` but you didn't assign it a value right away. The `ClassCastException` was thrown while *trying* to assign the `List<Object[]>` returned by Hibernate to your `List<Map<String,Object>>`. The error clrearly states that the cast to `Map` failed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a ResultTransformer to your query to accomplish this.  I am not sure if there is one that does what you want out of the box, though.  You may need to write your own.  It looks fairly simple, though.  I think all you would need would be to extend BasicTransformerAdapter and override the transformTuple method to return a map.  This should allow you to control the value returned from query.list() so you can set it directly on MappingBean.

Comment: what is result transformer?

Comment: It is a class provided by Hibernate that can be used to transform the result sets that are returned by Hibernate queries.  It lets you mish-mash into whatever format you want returned.  See the javadoc for org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer.